# Where are stockId gtk image stored?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm3

Where are stockId gtk image stored ?

I use gtkmm 3.24.5.

In gtkmm I display them as :

`// Note: This code is deprecated Gtk::Image image(Gtk:Stock::Yes.id, ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);`

I want to kown where image is stored on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the [icon theme](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/icon-theme-spec) that is currently applied.

On systems that conform to the Freedesktop.org Cross-Desktop Group (XDG) specification (Unix-like systems) they can be in a theme's subfolder that is located in any of the following paths (order is by precedence):

- `$HOME/.icons`
- `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`
- `/usr/share/pixmaps`

Where `$HOME` is the user's home directory, and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is [any path where data files are stored](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

If you'd like to find this information out programmatically, you can do something like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Display> display = Gtk::Widget::get_display();
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::IconTheme> icon_theme = Gtk::IconTheme::get_for_display(display);
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::IconPaintable> icon = icon_theme->lookup_icon("gtk-yes", 48);
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::File> icon_file = icon->get_file();
string icon_path = icon_file.get_path();
```

Be aware that if there is no icon found that uses that name and size, the `lookup_icon` method will simply return an `IconPaintable` that renders the "missing icon".

Since you are aware that stock icons are deprecated at this point, I recommend that you port your code to use newer techniques since you are likely to get weird results on newer systems. Someone would have to correct me, but I don't think stock icons are even included as a fallback in GNOME anymore.